# NSTimer Stops In Today Extension (Widget)

Tags: ios, today-extension

I'm creating a timer widget that uses a NSTimer. After starting the timer, if I close the Today Extension and open it the UI and NSTimer reloads. I do all of my setup in widgetPerformUpdateWithCompletionHandler except for some UI setup that I do in viewDidLoad. I want the NSTimer to continue to run in the background and when you reopen the Today Extension to show the current countdown time/continue running.

Sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Does it have to do with the lifecycle of the widget?

Comment: yes.  you can't rely on NSTimers when an app (or an extension) is in the background.  You need to store a start (or end) `NSDate` and calculate the elapsed/remaining time as required

Comment: @Paulw11 Okay thanks. For an app (not an extension) though can't I register the task in the background with beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler? Or is this still unreliable with NSTimers?

Comment: You can use that to execute a task for a short amount of time; a maximum of three minutes.  It is intended to give your app time to complete a task such as a file upload

Comment: @Paulw11Okay thanks. Looks like I'll be switching over to using NSDates then. Appreciate the help.